# Compare strings coming as char**

Tags: c++, c, string, char, string-comparison

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
   if ( *argv[2] == *argv[3]) { ... }
   return true;
}
```

It is wrong, isn't it?!

It's not my code, I found it, and, yes, I understand that we should check that we have more than 2 arquments...

Comment: And it's not specifically C++, C would be a better tag.

Answer (score 3):

For C++, construct `std::string` from each argument and then compare using `operator==`.

For C use `strcmp`.

For both, check `argc >= 4` before you do this check.

Comment: ssory, you want to say, that "by default" in C++ every  (char *) trasnform to std::string? Even if we exactly don't  do it?

Comment: Comparing strings is typically done that way in C++, even if you start out with a `const char*` in hand.  `strcmp` is part of the C runtime - in C++ the Standard Library provides `std::string` to ease the pain and avoid common errors such as buffer overrun, forgetting to free the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char  ** argv ) 
{
   if (argc >= 4 &&  std::string(argv[2]) == std::string(argv[3])) { ... }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp`, see here:

- http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231162

You can use `string` class for pure C++ if you want, see here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's wrong.

You need `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a perfectly valid code, but it probably doesn't do what you would expect.
`If condition` will be true if `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` begin with the same letter because you compare first character of both strings. If you want to compare entire strings use `strcmp`.

And 2 more advices:
When you deal with arguments always check their count (argc).
When you exit main thread the standard is to return 0 if everything is fine.